# Azure Stream Analytics Event Hub output - received invalid object

Tags: azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

Using ASA job with input as IoT Hub and Event Hub as Output with one streaming unit and 36 messages per second.

ASA send multiple objects as single string to event hub.

E.g. - When i test ASA job with uploading sample IoT Hub input json file, getting following object in single row(one object per row in output), which is expected - "{"assetbarcode":"MobileGW153353803144884Asset","sensorruleid":1159,"groupid":681}"

But When start ASA job and started C# event hub receiver getting multiple objects as single string-
"{"assetbarcode":"MobileGW153353803144884Asset","sensorruleid":1159,"groupid":681}
{"assetbarcode":"MobileGW153353803144884Asset","sensorruleid":1159,"groupid":681}
{"assetbarcode":"MobileGW153353803144884Asset","sensorruleid":1159,"groupid":681}"

So it failed to deserialize as it's invalid json. String is not a array or comma separated object.

referred C# receiver - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs/blob/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs/SampleEphReceiver/SimpleEventProcessor.cs

Comment: That SimpleEventProcessor you refer to does *not* deserialize the json string. So instead it shows the json data as a single string. Nothing wrong here.

Comment: But it's invalid json string, expecting one message/object as eventData but i am getting multiple object in single json string.

Answer (score 1):

If you configured your output to be line separated, this output is expected. To deserialize, you can read line by line and deserializer each line or let the deserializer sequence of JObjects.

If you prefer json array instead, please select array. [This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-define-outputs) has more details. Please note that if the job restarts before closing the file, the file might be missing closing "]"

Comment: I have files missing closing `]` but it seems to happen quite frequently whether or not I restart the job, making the array format pretty useless.